# Error: Cannot find module '../'

Tags: npm, vue.js

I got an error after copying a running project into another folder.

My setup:

```
vue init webpack-simple foo
cd foo
npm install
npm run dev
```

This works as expected: My browser opens and shows the typical vue index page.

Now let's suppose that I'm on a train with no internet and want to create another project from `foo`:

If I copy `foo` into `bar` and go to the directory and run `npm run dev` I got the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '../'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:470:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:418:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:498:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/fer/wokspace/udemy/foo/node_modules/.bin/cross-env:4:9)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
```

Why is this happening? The error does not happen if I **move** the folder instead of copy it

Comment: Possibly `vue init` is doing something under the hood with your directory name? I haven't look at it, but you could try copying and renaming it the same as your original to see if that works.

Comment: Hi, I am not able to reproduce this issue.